# How can I share my own spatial data on an online map?

Tags: open-source-gis, layers, tiles

Note: I am very new in this field!

Can I find an open source map that enables me to display an overlay of my own layers?

I need to add some text and rectangles for a certain area, but my modification must be on the tile level (500 mt height as example)?

I have a big work area; I need to make a new layer that determines every engineer’s works area, to be shown for my customer.
I need to provide him an interactive map, that when he zoom in the area, he will find the details when he reach 500 meter height, I need to r3epeat this method for more than one area in UAE country, and this is the reason why I need it to be an interactive map.

Example:

This is UAE country map:
[image]

This is Abu Dhabu emirates map:
[image]

This is area map:
[image]

I need to put an overlay on them (from the source data of the rectangles and text, which I included in the question), And I need to show them in web tool or any easiest way.

Comment: Hi! welcome to GIS.Stackexchange. Your question needs more details; What map tiles do you need to modify? What modifications do you want to make? Do you have read&write access to the actual tiles? Please edit the question and provide this information. You could also add an image which shows what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The change is a lot better, but you still haven't told us enough to work with this. Do you really want to modify the tiles, or would putting an overlay on them (from the source data of the rectangles, which you need to include in the question) do instead? Are you showing this in some web tool (like openlayers or leaflet) or some GIS tool? If so, which one.

Comment: @BradHards I need to put an overlay on them (from the source data of the rectangles and text, which I included in the question), And I need to show them in web tool or any easiest way.

Comment: What is the *format* of the source data? Shapefiles, database, word document? What tools do you already have? What options for client and server technology have you researched / considered? What were the results of that consideration?

Comment: @BradHards I do my apologies for my unawareness! but I think my data source will be a shape files since I want to add some rectangles with text. I will use QGIS as Mr. Andre Joost suggested, and I will provide online webpage to provide such a service.

Comment: @MRAN Are you looking for an online solution to display your custom map overlay?

Comment: @mapsir I'm looking for online or offline solution to present my map with my custom layers.

Comment: @MRAN Did you already set up anything in web? Can I see the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you serve the tiles locally, you can edit tiles with gimp or any other graphics program.

Overlaying the same content is quite easy when you create a tile with transparent background, add it as second layer, and overwrite the original tile.

---

**EDIT**

With the details you provided now, it might be better to create a vector layer with QGIS, then create transparent tiles to overlay over Openstreetmap or Google tiles. QGIS has a QTile plugin to create such tiles.

Openlayers is able to display as many transparent layers over a background map as you want. You can even have clickable features on such a map, or display vector data directly without the need to create transparent tiles.

Comment: This sounds great, but could you guide me more in details and suggestions?

Comment: So, I need to install QGIS, then Qtile plugin, and this will provide me the ability to create vector layers those I can use them with either Openstreetmap, google tiles or Openlayers, Is that correct?

Comment: You create the vector layer with QGIS, and Openlayers is used to display vector data and OSM or Google background. Openlayers can also draw vectors directly without the need to create transparent tiles: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/behavior-fixed-http-gml.html and http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/geojson-reprojected.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest that you look into the software called [tilemill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/)

It's an excellent software for creating custom Maps.

You could use OpenStreetmap's data and symbolize it according to your needs. You can then export the map to tilemill's mbtile format.

Once you have the mbtile file, you can either serve your web map directly from it, or you can export the tiles from it, using [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but is there any easiest way to add a certain text to be appeared in a certain point on the map? I need to add a text every 100*100 m2 on the map..

Comment: @MRAN This sounds like a new question which you should probably ask as such, but in the meantime can you use the edit button beneath your original Question to revise it with the additional details that have been requested, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo Sorry for the inconvenience, I 've updated my inquiry!